# VBA Excel: Dec2Hex more than one place

Tags: vba, excel

In a macro (shown below), I convert a row of cells from Decimal to Hexadecimal. When I use the normal Dec2Hex conversion (NOT in VBA), I am able to get two places (8 --> 08). However, when I use Dec2Hex conversion IN VBA, I can't seem to get 2 places until I actually need to characters (8 --> 8 BUT 10 --> 0A). How could I force that last character without just adding on a 0. Thanks!

**FOLLOW UP**

One interesting thing I noticed is if you look in the macro, I add a space after each hex value. However, when looking at the resulting file, a space is only added when two characters are present.

**SAMPLE**

F3 07 00 31 FA 10 //

F3 07 00 31 FB 20 //

F3 07 00 31 FC 00 //

F3 25 00 31 FF 830B 5114// <-- Notice the odd spacing. It should look like ...08 03 0B...

F3 07 00 31 FA 11 //

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim stream As TextStream
Dim FilePath As String
Dim saveDialog As Variant
Dim hexVal As String
Dim updateRate As String

'"N" is selected elsewhere by the user and simply dictates how far down a row cells are active     


For i = 4 To N + 3
    Cells(3, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(Cells(2, i), 2) & " "
Next i

For i = 4 To N + 3
    hexVal = hexVal & Cells(3, i)
Next i

updateRate = ComboBox1.Value

saveDialog = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Script Files(*.us1),*.us1")

    Set stream = fso.OpenTextFile(saveDialog, ForWriting, True)

        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 10 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FB " + updateRate + " // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FC 00 // "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 25 00 31 FF " + hexVal + "// "
        stream.WriteLine "F3 07 00 31 FA 11 // "

    stream.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/53719-leading-zero-hex-number.html  The DEC2HEX function returns text so you won't be able to use a number format. Try this formula:
=Dec2Hex(A1,2).  (you already are...) The problem I think is that the cells 3,i are numeric or general.  Either of these will truncate leading zeros.  However, if you change the cell format to TEXT the leading zero will not get truncated before you write out to the file.

Comment: @xQbert changing the Hex value cells to TEXT did the trick. Would you mind submitting an answer so I can give you the credit/close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is that the cells 3,i are numeric or general. Either of these will truncate leading zeros. However, if you change the cell format to TEXT the leading zero will not get truncated before you write out to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You did:

```
> For i = 4 To N + 3
>     Cells(3, i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(Cells(2, i), 2) & " " 
> Next i
> 
> For i = 4 To N + 3
>     hexVal = hexVal & Cells(3, i) 
> Next i
```

First, VBA (Excel) has the "hex()" function, why you use worksheetfunction.dec2hex?
Second, why you use a cell to store your hex for later retrieve and insert into the hexval?

You can replace both with:

```
For i = 4 To N + 3
    hext = hex(cells(2,i)) & " "
    Cells(3, i) = hext
    hexVal = hexVal & hext
Next i
```

If you want even number of digits in hex values, for example "B" becomes "0B", 3FC becomes 03FC, then:

```
For i = 4 To N + 3
    hext = hex(cells(2,i)) & " "
    if len(hext) Mod 2 = 0 then hext = "0" & hext
    Cells(3, i) = hext  ' if you really need Cells(3,i) to store it
    hexVal = hexVal & hext
Next i
```